# How to chain filters / filtering two object lists in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

Need some help in writing a filter query.

I have the following Models:

```
class Product:
    pid
    name

class WishList:
    user
    items = models.ManyToManyFields(Product)

class Stock:
    storeid
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    aisle
    segment
```

I need to :

1. Get the Current Logged in USER
2. Get the Products in the User's WishList
3. Search for those Products in the 'Stock' for a Particular StoreID passed as argument and display them along with their Aisle

This is what I did:

```
user = request.user
wish_list = get_object_or_404(WishList, user=user)

list_items = wish_list.items.all()
store_stocks = Stock.objects.filter(storeid=(passed StoreID))
list_stocks store_stocks.filter(store_stocks.pid=list_items.pid)
```

But it doesn't work and I need some help.

I get the Error as:

```
list_stocks = store_stocks.filter(store_stocks.pid=list_items.pid)
                                 |
SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression
```

Comment: `store_stocks.pid` is indeed not a valid parameter name.

Answer (score 1):

You can not write:

```
filter(store_stocks.pid=list_items.pid)
```

since the parameter name `store_stocks.pid` is invalid.

We can do this in a single query with:

```
from django.db.models import F

products = Product.objects.filter(
    wishlist__user=request.user,
    stock__storeid=store_id
).annotate(
    aisle=F('stock__aisle')
)
```

This will result in a queryset that contains `Product`s with an extra attribute `aisle` that is the `aisle` of the `Stock` for the given *`store_id`*. This will thus make it more convenient (likely), to render the `Product`s along with the corresponding `aisle`.

Note that a user can have *multiple* wishlists, and thus in that case we thus get all the products of all the wishlists. In case an item occurs on multiple wishlists, it will be listed *multiple* times.

This query will thus make two `JOIN`s: one with the `wishlist` table, and one with the `stock` table.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by:

```
list_items = wish_list.items.all()
list_stocks = Stock.objects.filter(storeid=(passed StoreID), product__in=list_items)
```